# Application Structure for GUI & Functions

Tags: python, user-interface, structure

I'm starting a basic application using Python and PyQt and could use some experienced insight. Here's the structure I was thinking. This is understandably subjective, but is there a better way?

```
myApp/GUI/__init__.py
          mainWindow.py
          subWindow1.py
          subWindow2.py

myApp/Logic/__init__.py
            setOfMethods1.py
            setOfMethods2.py


mainWindow imports subWindows
mainWindow imports Logic module
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### MVC

It looks like you have been reading about model-view-controller.

Separating the UI from the back end is a good idea.  It will make runnings tests and debugging just the logic side easier, and the internal structure will be more modular.

I'm not certain it makes as much sense to split the UI into the currently anticipated windows, though. I might just let the UI part grow and factor for common code.